# Using the definition of the limit to prove a sequence converges (solution check).

Tags: limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I understand that this type of question is asked a lot but I just wanted to make sure my approach is correct.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{3n^2 + 2n + 1}{n^2 - 2n - 3} = 3$$

is the problem in question.  The proof:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, $\left|\frac{3n^2 + 2n + 1}{n^2 - 2n - 3} - 3\right |$ =  $\left|\frac{8n + 10}{n^2 - 2n - 3}\right |$ = $\left|\frac{2(4n + 5)}{n(4n + 5) - 3 - 3n^2 - 7n}\right | \leq \left|\frac{2(4n + 5)}{n(4n + 5)}\right |$.  So $\frac{2(4n + 5)}{n(4n + 5)}$ < $\epsilon$ implies $\frac{2}{\epsilon} < n$.  Thus for $N = \frac{2}{\epsilon}$, $\forall n \geq N$, $\left|\frac{3n^2 + 2n + 1}{n^2 - 2n - 3} - 3\right | < \epsilon$.

I didn't know what to do about the polynomial so I just added by zero and used the fact that the above was less than a known convergent series, $\frac{2}{n}$.  Is this the proper approach or do I have the wrong idea in mind?

Comment: Your approach is ok, but notice that you can't just drop $-3-3n^2-7n$, since $\Big|\frac{1}{n(4n+5)-3-3n^2-7n}\Big| \geq \frac{1}{n(4n+5)}$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
$$\Big|\frac{8n+10}{n^2-2n-3}\Big| = \Big|\frac{8n+10}{(n+1)(n-3)}\Big| \leq \Big|\frac{8n+10+2n}{(n+1)(n-3)}\Big|$$

Comment: Sorry, but isn't it actually 8n + 10?  I have to edit my question because I put the wrong sign down.  Oops.  

So if that's the case, would I still be okay with $8n - 10 \leq 10n + 10$ by the same rationale as above?

Comment: In fact it is, sorry I didn't check your computations. But don't worry the same trick works in this case. See update :)